# Function calls parent class method instead of child?

Tags: c++, c++11

I try to figure out what is happening here, and I dont know. Please help.

```
class A
{
protected:
    string name;
public:
    A(string a) {name = a;}
    virtual string getName() {return "A name: " + name;}
};


class B: public A
{
public:
    using A::A;
    string getName() {return "B name: " + name;}
};


void print_name(A obj)
{
    cout << obj.getName() << endl;
}


int main()
{

    A a("a");
    B b("b");

    print_name(a);
    // "A name: a"

    print_name(b);
    // "A name: b"  why not "B name: b"????

    return 0;
}
```

Why second call to print_name(b); give "A name: b". It means that getName() from A class is executed, but it should be from B class? I made method virtual.

Comment: Read about [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing). `obj` parameter of `print_name` is actually an instance of `A` copy-constructed from `a` or `b`. It's never an instance of `B`, so `B::getName` can't possibly be called.

Comment: Can I fix it somehow? Whats the point of polyformism if I cant use child object through base class?

Comment: You fix it by having the function take its parameter by reference or by pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you had: `class B : public int`. Would there be any *value* of an `int` that's an instance of this class? Clearly not.

Now consider:

```
class B: public A
...
void print_name(A obj)
```

The `print_name` function takes an `A` by value. Is there any *value* of an `A` that is an instance of `B`? Again, no.

Perhaps you wanted:

```
void print_name(A& obj)
```

A reference to an `A` can be a `B`.

Comment: *A reference to an `A` can refer to a `B`

Comment: If you had a typical "is this a B` function and passed it a reference to an `A` that referred to a `B`, your function would report that the reference *is* a `B`.