# Base class has no new method error

Tags: c++, c++11

This is follow up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28534089/function-calls-parent-class-method-instead-of-child). Now I have this code:

```
class A
{
protected:
    string name;
public:
    A(string a) {name = a;}
    virtual string getName() {return "A name: " + name;}
};


class B: public A
{
public:
    using A::A;
    string getName() {return "B name: " + name;}
    string newMethod() {return "B name new: " + name;}
};


void print_name(A & obj)
{
    // HOW to check if obj is B, and call newMethod then.
    cout << obj.newMethod() << endl; // THIS LINE HAS ERROR below
}


int main()
{


    A a("a");
    B b("b");

    print_name(a);
    print_name(b);

    return 0;
}
```

I get error **'class A' has no member named 'newMethod'**. I know its becasue newMethod is only in B.

But how can I check if obj in print_name is A or B, and call newMethod only if obj is B?

Comment: Why do you want `B` to have *two* methods that print the name? If you don't want to use `B::getName()` in `print_name`, then where do you want to use it?

Comment: This is only example. I try to understand how inheritance works, what can be done with it, what cant, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is not a great design. But you can write:

```
cout << dynamic_cast<B &>(obj).newMethod() << endl;
```

This will throw an exception if `obj` is not actually a `B`. If you don't want an exception then you can cast to a pointer:

```
B *ptr = dynamic_cast<B *>(&obj);

if ( ptr )
    cout << ptr->newMethod() << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is trick, use dynamic_cast

```
TYPE& dynamic_cast<TYPE&> (object);
TYPE* dynamic_cast<TYPE*> (object);
```

dynamic_cast can only be used with pointers and references to classes (or with void*). Its purpose is to ensure that the result of the type conversion points to a valid complete object of the destination pointer type.

[dynamic_cast Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cby9kycs.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This is the way to use a virtual method:

```
class B: public A
{
public:
  ...
  // new implementation of virtual method, old signature
  string getName() {return "B name new: " + name;}
};    

void print_name(A & obj)
{
  cout << obj.getName() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is failing since the newMethod is not declared in class A,obviously the object reference of the class A will not find the method named newMethod.
To achieve what you want you should use concepts of RTTI use typeof operator.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dynamic casting:

```
void print_name(A & obj)
{
    B * b = dynamic_cast<B*>(&obj);

    if (b != nullptr) {            
        cout << b->newMethod() << endl; 
    } else { 
       cout << obj.getName() << endl;
    }
}
```